# Using Ezoic (or Adsense) with VueJS v2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, adsense

I have a new version of my site which uses VueJS v2 (the previous one didn't). The main code is placed inside `<div id="app"></div>` and Vue is initiated. The issue is that I partner with an advertising company called [Ezoic](https://ezoic.com) that injects ads through using AI onto the page, but these **ads aren't displaying properly**. I believe it is related to these errors:

> https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js
>   show_ads.js:53 Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't
>   possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded
>   external script unless it is explicitly opened.

Ezoic works with Google Ad Exchange, so I believe it is the above line that's related to the issue.

I'm wondering, is there any way in which I could make my application compatible with Ezoic/Adsense? I thought about having Vue on the page only where needed, rather than the entire page (`<div id="app"></div>` goes from the start of body to the end of body), but this would mean I need [multiple Vue instances](https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/using-multiple-vue-instances-page) running as I have components at the top (search box) and also throughout the pages.

I have no access to the code that Ezoic inject onto the page as this is done on their end (my site uses their DNS and they modify the response before sending to the visitor, to include the ad code). Ezoic team is also having a look into this issue presently but any information I could pass along could be helpful!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having a similar issue with Next.JS and Ezoic.

Comment: My *solution* was to use multiple Vue instances. It's not ideal by any means, and it means I needed to replace certain functionalities with jQuery/vanilla JS. You can reference between Vue instances by casting them on "window", which helps. To elaborate, you can place ad code outside of the Vue instances (e.g. outside <div id="app"></div>)

Comment: It's really unfortunate that I need to split my entire Vue application in half in order to insert an ad. I wish Ezoic provided better controls around triggering ad fills. Injecting code via CDN is frankly a trash solution. Something I'd like to try if I ever get time is to take the injected code and manually apply it during the Vue mount event.

Comment: I know this is old, but did you try defining your placeholders using the ezstandalone.define() function after your placeholder dom element loaded?

Comment: Hey @user10012... can you please proivde an example? If my placeholder id is ezoic-pub-ad-placeholder-111 then ezstandalone.define(131); would be the expression? Thanks!

Comment: @DynamicRemo answer posted. It's kind of specific to my use case, but should give you an idea of the whole process.

Answer (score 2):

At the request of **Dynamic Remo** I am submitting an answer for Ezoic's standalone implementation that is compatible with Vue.

*I will however preface this with they absolutely hate it when you install it this way and essentially refuse to support it. - with that said you have way more control over placement*

The Solution:
First add the following script tag somewhere outside  or your custom defined root element.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.ezojs.com/ezoic/sa.min.js" async=""></script>
```

In your vue component you will need to create all your placeholder elements with a id of "ezoic-pub-ad-placeholder-xx" where xx is replaced by the actual id found in your enzoic dashboard. Dynamic creation does work as long as there is a matching id in ezoic so you have two options:

**Dynamic:**

```
<div v-for="placeholderId in ezoicArray" :id="'ezoic-pub-ad-placeholder-' + placeholderId" class="ezoic"></div>
```

**Standard:**

```
<div id="ezoic-pub-ad-placeholder-102" class="ezoic"></div>
```

To actually display ads in your placeholders you can use this function I wrote. Just call it when the component is mounted.

```
ezoic(placeholderList) {
  if (window.ezstandalone !== undefined) {
    window.ezoicPlaceholderArray = window.ezoicPlaceholderArray || [];

    // Add Placeholders to Array
    placeholderList.forEach((placeholder) => {
      this.addPlaceholderOnce(window.ezoicPlaceholderArray, placeholder);
    });

    // Enable Once - Refresh on Change
    window.ezoicRefreshed = false;
    window.ezoicEnabled = window.ezoicEnabled || false;

    // Next Tick Ensures All Enzoic Blocks Are Loaded
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      // On First Load We Must Enable
      if (!window.ezoicEnabled) {
        window.ezstandalone.define(window.ezoicPlaceholderArray);
        window.ezoicPlaceholderArray = null;
        console.log('ezoic defined and array reset');
        window.ezstandalone.enable();
        console.log('ezoic enabled');
        window.ezstandalone.display();
        console.log('ezoic displayed');
        window.ezoicEnabled = true;
        window.ezoicRefreshed = true;
      }

      // On Refresh We Have To Destroy & Refresh
      if (!window.ezoicRefreshed) {
        window.ezstandalone.destroy();
        console.log('ezoic destroyed');
        window.ezstandalone.define(window.ezoicPlaceholderArray);
        window.ezoicPlaceholderArray = null;
        console.log('ezoic refresh defined and array reset');
        window.ezstandalone.refresh();
        console.log('ezoic refreshed');
        window.ezoicRefreshed = true;
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log('Error: Missing Ezoic Standalone');
  }
},
addPlaceholderOnce(array, placeholder) {
  if (!array.includes(placeholder)) {
    array.push(parseInt(placeholder));
    console.log('ezoic-pub-ad-placeholder-' + placeholder + ' - Created');
  }
},
```

If you need to change your placeholder setup for different reasons as I do simply add `window.ezoicRefreshed = false;` to the appropriate lifecycle hook. In my case I have it in beforeUnmount because each route gets a custom placeholder list.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you @user10012, really appreciate this.
So the two functions ezoic() and addPlaceholderOnce() are in Vue component and on the Component Init Constructor? Right?

Will try to adapt the similar concept in my Angular App. Lastly, did the EPMV, CPM  improved? How is it going? Thanks again <3

Comment: Correct those need to be ran when the component gets created. The commands in the this.$nextTick callback need to be executed after the entire dom has loaded. I'm not sure what Angular's version of this is, but nextTick works in vue. As far as EPMV improvements I had nothing on there prior to compare, but my Ezoic rep said its on the high end for comparable sites and has been increasing ( along with my traffic ) over the past month.

Comment: Yeah placed it in NgOnInit which is executed when the component is initialized and it works; the Ads are showing. Thanks for that... and since you are the expert for me; how do you tackle Consent Management Dialog? I can not find any helpful resource yet with TCF 2.0. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Hey @user10012 reaching out to your as a fellow publisher on Ezoic; since you are the only one I found have somewhat similar setup based on JS (mine is Angular+Node).

Did the CPM and revenue got better with the time? Because with your guidance here my Ads are now showing and my Quantcast CMP also works fine... but even after two weeks the revenue is still negligible as compare to my old Advertisers. Do you think its worth a wait? and continue with Ezoic? Thanks in advance again :-)

Comment: Hi @user10012, I have tried to implement your solution and it kinda works, but ads can take as long as 4-5 seconds to appear, and it looks like they are reloaded once or twice (also I see lots of errors in my website console). Do I need to do any extra steps? For example disable other integrations (cloudflare).

Comment: @Vektor88 The ads will take longer to load as this method loads all the content before loading the ads. How long that takes will depend on a lot of things especially your server. I account for this my design. However 4-5 seconds sounds extreme. If you have multiple integration methods you absolutely want to drop that to a single method.

Comment: @DynamicRemo EPMC depends on a lot of factors. I have two sites using this method. One gets almost $30 epmc and the other gets just over half that. I found the # of placeholders for testing makes a big difference. Also the larger one is mostly filled with "buying" articles vs info content. I feel like that is also playing a role.

Comment: Thank you for the response @user10012. I dont get this part "Also the larger one is mostly filled with "buying" articles vs info content. I feel like that is also playing a role." Can you please explain this? ... One more question; your sites are web applications or traditional blog on Javascript Stack? Can you tell more about your technology stack and only the type of your site? Thanks again :-)

Comment: @DynamicRemo they are blogs using a custom CMS that I built with a PHP api and a Vue 2 front end.  The high EPMC site has a lot of "Best of x for Y" articles meaning people are are in the buying cycle and actively looking to buy a product. The other is informational "how to" articles. My guess is that Ezoic knows the former are active buyers and that's boosting the epc.  But again I'm just guessing. There are lots of factors in EPMC. How many placeholders are you testing and what is your traffic?

Comment: I am testing with around 10placeholders on each page... and traffic is around 4-5k page views per day. The thing is; that I often see 5 Ads visible on any test reload of my app but the revenue is not getting better, its the same as it was in first week after setting up Ezoic :-/

Comment: @user10012 any more idea? suggestions or something? mine is on mean stack implementation. Thank you!

Comment: @DynamicRemo I am pushing almost 30 placeholders per page mixed between my content and sidebar. It's also important to note that ezoic software knows that you are the account owner and will show you more ads than it will a normal visitor. Make the last placeholder in your sidebar sticky, and ensure you have the footer ad turned on.